# Extract N strings from an xml based file

Tags: xml, awk, data-extraction, xmlstarlet

I am currently fighting with awk to extract multiple strings from xml based files, and export those strings in a csv format

below snippet of the tags I am trying to get :

```
    <GroupInfo Description="" Name="Site 2" Path="My Company\Site 2"/>
    ...
    ...
    <PrivateInsightServerList EnableEntireServerList="1" >
      <PrivateInsightServer Address="douda" LegacyClientSupport="1" Port="80" Protocol="HTTP"/>
    </PrivateInsightServerList>
    <PrivateInsightServerList EnableEntireServerList="1" >
      <PrivateInsightServer Address="douda2" LegacyClientSupport="0" Port="443" Protocol="HTTPS"/>
    </PrivateInsightServerList>
```

I do not know how to parse the file knowing the amount of servers from the xml can vary from 0 to N, but always are with the same structure.

Ideally, I am looking for the following in a csv, and add the N servers from the same xml file to the same line like this :

```
path,address,port,protocol
```

eg. from the snippet :

```
My company\site 2,douda,80,HTTP,douda2,443,HTTPS
```

Comment: Use an XML parser to parse XML data. Please post a minimal, complete, valid XML sample data so we can help you more easily: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Let's just add the obligatory [You can't parse XML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's required, and you haven't provided it, I have assumed your root XML element is simply "`<root>`".

The XML isn't nicely nested (I would have expected `PrivateInsightServerList` to be a child of `GroupInfo`), we will need a little trickery. No matter.

First, with `xmlstarlet`

```
xml sel -t -m '/root/GroupInfo' --var groupinfo=@Path \
  -m '/root/PrivateInsightServerList[@EnableEntireServerList=1]' \
    -v '$groupinfo' -o "," \
    -v PrivateInsightServer/@Address -o "," \
    -v PrivateInsightServer/@Port -o "," \
    -v PrivateInsightServer/@Protocol -nl \
  input.xml
```

- `-m '/root/GroupInfo' --var groupinfo=@Path`
  this stores the Path attribute in a variable for later use
- `-m '/root/PrivateInsightServerList[@EnableEntireServerList=1]'` limits the nodes selected in case `EnableEntireServerList` is not 1
- each `-v ... -o ","` outputs the values we want, followed by newline (`-nl`)

(Instead of a variable to cache `Path` you could also use a "sibling" XPath like
`-v //GroupInfo/@Path` but that may not work reliably, like I said the XML doesn't appear "nice" to me.)

Since you've also tagged this with `awk`, I'll assume you have a recent `gawk` and `gawkextlib` with the XML module (not that you can't do it in plain `awk`, but it's not very productive if learning about XML parsing isn't the task at hand).

```
@load "xml"

XMLSTARTELEM &&
  XMLPATH~/GroupInfo$/ { mypath=XMLATTR["Path"] }
XMLSTARTELEM &&
  XMLPATH~/PrivateInsightServerList$/ { ok=XMLATTR["EnableEntireServerList"] }
XMLSTARTELEM &&
   XMLPATH~/PrivateInsightServerList[/]PrivateInsightServer/ {
     if(ok==1) printf("%s,%s,%s,%s\n",
               mypath,XMLATTR["Address"],XMLATTR["Port"],XMLATTR["Protocol"])
}
```

This is a little primitive (I've not yet used the DOM `xmltree` module), there are three blocks above, each triggers on `XMLSTARTELEM` and inspects the `XMLPATH` containing the full XPath of the element. The first two blocks cache the `Path` and `EnableEntireServerList`, the final one prints out the CSV as required.

Run with `gawk -f parse.awk input.xml` (by "recent" I mean gawk-4.1 or later)

I would expect either method could have problems depending on the XML schema and ordering of data.

Comment: Thank you very much mr.spuratic.
It indeed helped and I did not show the whole xml structure as it's huge.
I did not know gawk, and once installed with xml extension, it worked as expected. thanks again !